# NameError: name 'models' is not defined when trying to create a migration

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm having an issue importing a models file using SqlAlchemy

In a env file I have:

```
import migrations.models

target_metadata = models.Base.metadata
```

and the models file is:

```
class User():
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    discord_id = Column(Text)
    server_id = Column(Text)
    name = Column(Text)
```

and my directory looks like

```
dir
|__ migrations
   |__ versions
   |__ env.py
   |__ models.py
```

and this throws an error when I try to generate the migrations

```
alembic revision --autogenerate -m 'adds user table'

target_metadata = models.Base.metadata
    NameError: name 'models' is not defined
```

Comment: You imported it as `migrations.models`, so you must also use that exact name when you refer to it.  `target_metadata = migrations.models.Base.metadata`

Comment: You could use `import migrations.models as models` to create a short name.

Answer (score 1):

Change this :

```
import migrations.models
```

To this :

```
from migrations import models
```